# How to implement filewatcher using Reactive extensions

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am new to Rx and looking to use it in my current project. I am trying to implement a file watcher system. Atleast for now I am only interested in file Creation event. But I am getting "Value cannot be null error message" when trying to run below code. 
Please could someone help me out with below code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IDisposable writer = new FileSystemObservable(@"D:\Code\Rx\Dropbox\", "*.*", false)
                            .CreatedFiles
                            .Where(x => (new FileInfo(x.FullPath)).Length > 0)
                            .Select(x => x.Name)
                            .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}


class FileSystemObservable
{
    private readonly FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher;

    public FileSystemObservable(string directory, string filter, bool includeSubdirectories)
    {
        fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(directory, filter)
            {
                EnableRaisingEvents = true,
                IncludeSubdirectories = includeSubdirectories
            };

        CreatedFiles = Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>
                (h => fileSystemWatcher.Created += h,
                h => fileSystemWatcher.Created -= h)
                .Select(x => new { x.EventArgs }) as IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs>;

        Errors = Observable.FromEventPattern<ErrorEventHandler, ErrorEventArgs>
                (h => fileSystemWatcher.Error += h,
                h => fileSystemWatcher.Error -= h)
                .Select(x => new { x.EventArgs }) as IObservable<ErrorEventArgs>;
    }

    public IObservable<ErrorEventArgs> Errors { get; private set; }

    public IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs> CreatedFiles { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of the

```
Select(x => new { x.EventArgs }) as IObservable<ErrorEventArgs>
```

and

```
.Select(x => new { x.EventArgs }) as IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs>;
```

lines will always return null.

The type of `Select(x => new { x.EventArgs })` is `IObservable<'a>` where `'a` is some anonymous type.

You should instead use:

```
CreatedFiles = 
    Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(
        h => fileSystemWatcher.Created += h,
        h => fileSystemWatcher.Created -= h)
    .Select(x => x.EventArgs);

Errors = 
    Observable.FromEventPattern<ErrorEventHandler, ErrorEventArgs>(
        h => fileSystemWatcher.Error += h,
        h => fileSystemWatcher.Error -= h)
    .Select(x => x.EventArgs);
```

Comment: Thanks Lee! Now the error has gone and I can compile the program. However, I dont get the list of files created.

Comment: In addition to this CreatedFiles and Errors need to be defined as IObservable<EventPattern<FileSystemEventArgs>> and IObservable<EventPattern<ErrorEventArgs>>

Comment: @NarayanAkhade - It works ok for me. I would subscribe to the watcher's events directly to make sure they are being raised as you expect, but I think your Observables are defined correctly.

Comment: @Dev - The `Select` clause gets the event args from the `EventPatter<T>` returned from `FromEventPattern`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lee! the problem was in the where clause which checks the file lenght! and I am creating files with 0KB for testing:(!